# Disable WebBrowser caching

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, browser-cache, flash, navigateurl

I am new here and really want your help.
I've been trying to disable my webbrowser's cache but I get overload resolution failed because no accessible "Navigate" without a narrowing conversion. I'm stuck and I don't know what to do anymore, I did search all the possible solutions but found no answer.
Here's my code:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Const navNoReadFromCache As Long = 4
        Const navNoHistory As Long = 2
        Const navNoWriteToCache As Long = 8
        Dim navflags As Long
        navflags = navNoHistory + navNoWriteToCache
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("url", 4)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Original Error message is:

Error   2   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Navigate' can be called without a narrowing conversion:

```
'Public Sub Navigate(urlString As String, newWindow As Boolean)': Argument matching parameter 'newWindow' narrows from 'Integer' to 'Boolean'.

'Public Sub Navigate(urlString As String, targetFrameName As String)': Argument matching parameter 'targetFrameName' narrows from 'Integer' to 'String'.
```

Comment: the code is VB but the question is about C++. something's missing here.

Comment: what do you want your `4` param to do? the error message is telling whatever you want to do with `4` is incorrect.

Comment: I want my four to stop reading cache. The whole idea is to stop my browser from reading and writing cache because I get a black screen.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong reference materials.  the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` doesnt take a Long or Int param for the Navigate method (hit F2 and search WebBrowser).  YOu might have read something for VB6 or the MSHTML stuff.

Comment: Maybe you are right but the whole purpose is to make my webbrowser1 to stop reading and saving cache, how can I do that?

Comment: To be more precise, I want to load a website that has .html and the contents run on java .swf. The black screen that I get is the loading screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time of searching and testing different methods I came with a good result.

Shell("RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 8", vbHide)

This is the code I used to delete the cache that held my web browser on a blackscreen.
What it does is search for the Internet Explorer's Temporary files and deletes them, the vbHide has to be kept next to the comma to work, what is does is hide the window that pops us telling you it deletes temp files.

Answer (score 1):

.NET WebBrowserControl doesn't have overload what accept int or long argument.
So, you can't set [BrowserNavConstants (this for IWebBrowser2 not .NET WebBrowserControl)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value to .NET WebBrowserControl.

---

I found following page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x214wa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> The WebBrowser control stores Web pages from recently visited sites in a cache on the local hard disk. Each page can specify an expiration date indicating how long it will remain in the cache. When the control navigates to a page, it saves time by displaying a cached version, if one is available, rather than downloading the page again.
>
> Use the Refresh method to force the WebBrowser control to reload the current page by downloading it, ensuring that the control displays the latest version.

---

Updated.
I try the code following, that looks like work fine :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.co.jp");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        webBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely);
    }
```

This loads page two times.

Comment: I've been using this wb1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely) when I get a black screen but it doesn't do anything. I've registered this to a button.

Comment: black? Umm... I think, the default background color is white. Did you see `wb1.DocumentText` after refresh?

Comment: Exactly, I found out it was cause of the temp files. I used ccleaner for this and every time I cleaned flash player and IE temps it start working again. But that won't fix my problem I want my webbrowser to stop storing that kind of data.

Comment: To be more precise, I want to load a website that has .html and the contents run on java .swf. The black screen that I get is the loading screen.

Comment: I think this is Flash Player's chache problem Rather than WebBrowserControl.

Comment: Ok... any ideas on how to fix this? Because if that's the case I'll know on what to concentrate on.

Comment: If possible, try to clear only Flash Player's cache. https://forums.adobe.com/message/4278569

Comment: Nope, it's not adobe's cache, it has to be IE. I just used ccleaner to clean only cache from adobe and nothing happened but when I cleaned IE cache it started working again.

Comment: even with the updated code I still can't get passed the black page, it has to do with IE cache.

Comment: I can't found any ideas, sorry. Old-fashioned way to avoid the cache, there is a method to add a meaningless query string in url (like "~.swf?a=20140622_105720"). 
However, I do not know this method can solve problem. And this is difficult from static. Html page.

Comment: can I at least save my app's cache in a file I want?